# Get letter from user and print out letter with its position in the alphabet

Tags: java

I want to have the user input a letter, and then print out the letter and its position in the alphabet. If the input isn't a letter, I want the program to print: `"Not valid"`.

How would I do that?

EDIT - Sorry for my unresponsiveness, I actually figured this out a few days ago. Heres the actual code though :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlphaPos {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(" Please enter an upper or lowercase letter. ");
           String letter = input.nextLine();

           String alpha = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
           String beta = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

         if((!alpha.contains(letter))&&(!beta.contains(letter))) 
              System.out.println(" You entered " +letter+ ", and you obviously can't follow directions."); 

        boolean hasUppercase = !letter.equals(letter.toLowerCase()); {
           if (hasUppercase) 
              System.out.println("Your letter is " +letter+ ", Uppercase, and its number is "+ beta.indexOf(letter));

        boolean hasLowercase = !letter.equals(letter.toUpperCase());
           if (hasLowercase)
                 System.out.println("Your letter is " +letter+ " ,lowercase , and its number is "+ alpha.indexOf(letter));
                                                                      }   

   }
}
```

School assignment, so this code has no purpose. And thanks for all the responses anyways!

Comment: Show us what have you tried, and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Please show your code, it will make it easier to see where exactly the problem is, thanks. And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Voting to close as Too Broad because the OP showed nothing and therefore narrowed nothing

Comment: FWIW - Once you learn about the runtime of programs, you'll know that your solution is not very "efficient"

Answer (score 2):

My simple testing verifies this works by taking advantage of the fact that `char` values are also evaluated to ASCII `int` values, so you can do some simple math as shown.

There are 26 possible positions for an English letter, so the if condition checks for out-of-bounds on that.

```
char c = 'd'; // Replace with user input like Scanner#next() or something

// output: 'A' = 1, 'Z' = 26
int position = (Character.toUpperCase(c) - 'A' + 1);

if (position < 1 || position > 26) {
    System.out.println("Not valid");
} else {
    System.out.println(String.format("Character: %s\nPosition: %d", c, position));
}
```

**Output**

```
Character: d
Position: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mine idea on first thought:

```
char c = ...
if(!Character.isLetter(c)) {
   return "Not valid!";
} else {
    System.out.println("Letter:"+c+", position: "+ "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".indexOf(c));
}
```

Comment: Maybe `toUpperCase(c)` at the end?

Comment: This answer is wrong. [`Character.isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-) lets pass other charaters than A-Z. And `indexOf` on the hardcoded alphabet is not very great: just do a simple calculation on the `char` value instead. Also, why do you assume the input is in uppercase? And why is one code path returning a value while the other one is printing something?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest way but robust and easy to understand:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            if (input.matches("[a-zA-Z]")) {
                System.out.println(input);
                char c = input.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).charAt(0);
                System.out.println(c - 96);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Not valid");
        }
    }
}
```

I use a regex to check if the input is a single character in the English alphabet, either lowercase or uppercase. If so, it is printed. To get the position in the alphabet, I converted it to lowercase (because both uppercase and lowercase have the same position) and subtracted its `int` value so to normalize `a` to `1`.

The loop is just there for easier testing.

Thanks to cricket_007 and Tunaki for improving the answer (see revisions for details).